# Bokeh Themes with yaml file

Tags: python, bokeh

Am new to Python and Bokeh. Trying to apply a simple theme to a simple line graph using a separate yaml file. Unsure as to how to do this. If this is my cell in my Juypter notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure, output_notebook
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral
from bokeh.themes import Theme
from bokeh.document import Document

output_notebook()

x_f = [1.5, 2, 9]
y_f = [3, 3, 3.1]

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
p.line(x_f, y_f, line_width=3, color=Spectral[4][0])

show(p)
```

---

And this is a separate file, lp.yaml

```
### Default attribute of Bokeh line chart
attrs:
    Figure:
        background_fill_color: "whitesmoke"
        background_fill_alpha: 0.5
```

How do I override the default themes with the attributes in the .yaml file?

Answer (score 3):

From your code, you can either have your app reading a theme from the default location (as suggested by @tony) or if you like you can store several custom themes files in YAML format and read them with:

`curdoc().theme = Theme(filename='path_to_theme.yaml)`

Assuming a directory structure like:

```
myapp
   |
   +---main.py
   +---theme.yaml
   +---templates
        +---index.html
   +---static
        +---css
            +---styles.css
        +---themes
            +---test_theme.yaml
```

the `path_to_theme.yaml` could be:
`os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'static', 'themes', 'test_theme.yaml')`

If you like to offer several layouts, you can add a widget to switch between themes, for example:

```py
# mybokeh_themes.py

from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral
from bokeh.themes import Theme
from bokeh.document import Document

# import some layout elements, a select widget, and the built_in_themes
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Select
from bokeh.themes import Theme, built_in_themes

def switch_theme(value, old, new):
    curdoc().theme = new


x_f = [1.5, 2, 9]
y_f = [3, 3, 3.1]

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
p.line(x_f, y_f, line_width=3, color=Spectral[4][0])


theme_select = Select(title='Theme', options=['caliber',
                                              'dark_minimal', 
                                              'light_minimal', 
                                              'night_sky', 
                                              'contrast'])
theme_select.on_change('value', switch_theme)

curdoc().add_root(column(theme_select, p))
```

you can test it with: `bokeh serve mybokeh_themes.py`

Answer (score 0):

the below should work in a jupyter notebook with Bokeh 12.16

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook, curdoc
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.themes import Theme


output_notebook()


theme = Theme(json={
    'attrs': {
        'Figure': {
            'background_fill_color': '#2F2F2F',
            'border_fill_color': '#2F2F2F',
            'outline_line_color': '#444444'
            },
        'Axis': {
            'axis_line_color': "white",
            'axis_label_text_color': "white",
            'major_label_text_color': "white",
            'major_tick_line_color': "white",
            'minor_tick_line_color': "white",
            'minor_tick_line_color': "white"
            },
        'Grid': {
            'grid_line_dash': [6, 4],
            'grid_line_alpha': .3
            },
        'Circle': {
            'fill_color': 'lightblue',
            'size': 10,
            },
        'Title': {
            'text_color': "white"
            }
        }
    })



x_f = [1.5, 2, 9]
y_f = [3, 3, 3.1]

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
p.line(x_f, y_f, line_width=3, color=Spectral[4][0])

doc = curdoc()
doc.theme = theme
doc.add_root(p)
show(p)
```

Comment: @birdarah it works for me in bokeh 12.16, but I am at my home computer and had to update it from 12.13 bc it did not work.  I am pretty sure I gave the above example when I was running bokeh 12.15 from my work computer.  I will try to remember and give versions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

See file structure below. Run as (tested with Bokeh v0.12.6):

```
bokeh serve --show myapp
```

File structure:

```
myapp
   |
   +---main.py
   +---theme.yaml
   +---templates
        +---index.html
```

main.py

```
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, show, figure, output_notebook
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral

output_notebook()

x_f = [1.5, 2, 9]
y_f = [3, 3, 3.1]

p = figure(plot_width = 400, plot_height = 400)
p.line(x_f, y_f, line_width = 3, color = Spectral[4][0])
curdoc().add_root(p)
```

theme.yaml

```
attrs:
    Figure:
        background_fill_color: "whitesmoke"
        background_fill_alpha: 0.5
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {{ bokeh_css }}
    {{ bokeh_js }}
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ plot_div|indent(8) }}
    {{ plot_script|indent(8) }}
  </body>
</html>
```