# Catch-all for font properties (e.g. font size) of a bokeh figure

Tags: python, bokeh

I know that I can access font size of individual models/annotations as e.g. `p.axis.major_label_text_font_size`. If I wanted to change, say, all font sizes and all font styles across an entire figure, that quickly becomes a lot of code (Legend, Axis labels and tick labels, Figure, Title, ...). Is there a way to access/set font size as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the best option would be to use [Bokeh themes](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/themes.html)

There are build-in themes but you can also define your own themes, save them in YAML or JSON format then load them dynamically and switch between them like this:

```
theme1 = Theme(filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/theme1.yaml'))
theme2 = Theme(filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/theme2.yaml'))

curdoc().theme = theme1
curdoc().theme = theme2
```

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756660/bokeh-themes-with-yaml-file)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there would be some property that could catch them all at once, but I suppose using a theme is pretty efficient already.